# Is it possible to change the attribute "title" of an <a> element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code, but I want to try to change the value of "**title**" in **CSS**. Is that possible?

I tried some ways, and the following CSS doesn't work also...How can I figure out?

```css
.icon {
  content: attr("A new title");
}
```

```html
<a class="icon" href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" title="View Youtube">LINK</a>
```

Comment: Use javascript where javascript is due.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it, but you can hack it using css. Check the code below.

```css
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
  content: 'sadasdsad';
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. <a href="#" title="Hello, i am a link">Vestibulum</a> tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. <a href="#" title="This is another link">Mauris placerat</a> eleifend leo.</p>
```

Comment: I don't think your code is changing the default title attr there.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri is right. You are not changing the title, you are just adding a pseudo element

Comment: You are right. I just put it in a wrong way. Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done by CSS. But if you can use JQuery. It can be done easily.

Check my solution using jQuery.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/ztdwx3pp/)**

```
$('.icon').prop('title', 'your new title');
```

Hope this help.